# Hibernate Работа с запросами

Tags: java, hibernate

Начал изучать Hibernate. Вроде как коннект с бд есть, но при попытки создать таблицы или сделать элементарный select ничего не происходит.

```
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard]
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
мар 27, 2016 9:04:33 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
мар 27, 2016 9:04:34 PM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
мар 27, 2016 9:04:34 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard]
```

Вот код:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSesssionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    List<User> users = null;

    try {
    session.beginTransaction();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
    users = criteria.list();

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    for(User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.toString());
    }
```

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name="id_user")
private Long id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="login")
private String login;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;
}//get&set
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskboard</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">1234</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="User" />
</session-factory>
```

Comment: Можно глянуть модель User

Comment: Да, добавил выше

Comment: Конфигурационный файл хибера

Comment: Так же добавил выше

Comment: Добавьте вот этот метод, пожалуйста `HibernateUtil.getSesssionFactory()`